# how to get checkbox value from database in php for update data?

Tags: php, web, checkbox, sql-update

in database values are stored as "A,B,C,D,E,F" etc.
now i have to fetch those data in the form for update.
i have to check the checkbox if it matches the value with database value.

i am doing this kind of code(which i know is wrong)

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="free" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'free')=="false") { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> />Free
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="Open" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'Open')=="false") { echo "checked='checked'"; }?>/>Open Source
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="portable" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'portable')=="false") { echo "checked='checked'"; }  ?> />Portable
    <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="support" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'support')=="false") {
                        echo "checked='checked'"; }?> />Support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When strpos is 0 (first character), then it is equal to false if you use double = (==). You need to use ===false. Besides it should be `false`, not `"false"`.

Comment: I can't see why first row differs from the others. For html file, it is correct.

Comment: first line which is not working: <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="free" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'free')==false) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> />Free

Comment: right lines:<input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="Open" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'], 'Open')==false) { echo "checked='checked'"; }?>/>Open Source

Comment: you still use == instead of ===

Comment: maybe the key is uppercase "Free" - in that case either change to "Free" or change strpos to stripos which is case insensitive

Comment: "===" is not working,i am already check with "F"ree which is also not working...<input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="free" <?php if(!strpos($row['best'],'free')===false) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> />Free

Comment: ok i just find out that whatever word is find first in the database column it is not able to checked in the check box.like "free,open,portable" then above code is not able to check "free"

Comment: that's something I cannot see, but those errors from my answer were real, I hope that was good answer :)

Comment: i did not get it too,even your "===" is not working & false instead of "false" is working but not able to get word from the database if it occur first in the index

Comment: You would have to show the code before those inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

suppose you have four static values :
<

```
?php
$time = ['free', 'open' , 'portable', 'support']; // your checkboxes
$fromDb = explode(',', $row['best']);
foreach($time as $t):
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $t;?>" <?php if(in_array($t, $fromDb) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> /><?php echo ucfirst($t);?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $t;?>" <?php if(in_array($t, $fromDb) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?> /><?php echo ucfirst($t);?>

Comment: i think that error is because the database value which i fetch is not converted into array or may be fromDb is not an array...but i am not sure about it