# how to get checkbox value as checked from database in php?

Tags: checkbox

in database values are stored as "A,B,C,D,E,F" etc. now i have to fetch those data in the form for update. i have to check the checkbox if it matches the value with database value.

```
$rs=sql("select sectionName from sections where sectionName != ' ' order by sectionName");
$cat_options="";
foreach($rs as $d){
    $option=$d['sectionName'];
    $cat_options.= "<label><input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value='$option'>$option</label><br/>";
}
```

It retrieve list of category from one table.

```
$a = explode(",", $category);
```

`$a` is array of name of category that should be checked in list of category.

I already knew that there are lots off topics on net related to my topics. I tried them but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT sectionName from sections";
$result = @mysql_query ($query);
while($drop=@mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='category[]' value=$drop[sectionName]>$drop[sectionName]";
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand your question completely but from my point of view you want to retrive value from database and display it in checkbox.

Comment: how can I get checkbox value as checked by this??

Comment: if you click on any checkbox then it store the value in your database where you want to add

Comment: i suggest you that please try to run this code first then reply what you get

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759615/how-to-get-checkbox-value-from-database-in-php-for-update-data  refer this link you will understand my question

Comment: yes the question is same you have to retrive value from database and then show it on checkbox

Comment: but checked that value that are previously added into databas

Comment: but if you add new value to database then it also show in checkbox.It will automatically update all the value